# Get only temp core from sensors

Tags: sensors

I'm trying to retrieve only the temp of the 4 cores, to display them into my terminal (I needed them separated).

My original output is :

```
(OC) √ ~ $ sensors                                                                                            ~ 9:24:24
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +68.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +66.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.98 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        3757 RPM

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
```

I tried with awk, but not enough and I didn't know how I could retrieve the temp and separate them to have a result like :

```
Core n°1 : 63°C         Core n°2 : 64°C         Core n°3 : 67°C         Core n°4 : 85°C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
sensors | awk -F '(' '/^Core/{gsub("[[:space:]]+"," "); printf "%s\t", $1}'
```

- `(` as a field delimiter
- `/^Core/` to extract lines only which starts with 'Core'
- `gsub("[[:space:]]+"," ");` to replace multiple successive spaces to single space as per expected result
- `"%s\t",` to print all results in same line with tab delimiter.

Comment: Wow, perfetct ! thanks a lot !